# dry run query regarding loops in C language

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C language and while I was studying loops in C language then I encountered few issues in loops, for example in the given below `code-1` and `code-2`.

When I am performing dry run then `code-1` is running the loop for 6 times (starting from i=1 till i=6), which is understandable by me but I am bit wondering regarding the dry run for code-2 (whether it will run for 5 times or 6 times).

----Sample Code---

For example in the 2 given codes:

Code-1

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=1;
    while(i<=5)
    {
        printf("AA_Float");
        i++;
     }
     getch();
}
```

Code-2

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i=1;
   do
   {
       printf("AA_Float");
       i++;
   }  while(i<=5);
   getch();
}
```

Comment: Either compile it and find out or run through it on paper.

Comment: [Just run it here](http://ideone.com/) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for code 1 the looping count equals the number of times the check "i<=5" passes. for code 2 the looping count equals the number of times the check "i<=5" happens. for code 1 i is 1 when the first check passes, therefore it passes for 5 times. the loop runs 5 times. for code 2 i is 2 when the first check happens (and passes). therefore it passes for 4 times. note that the number of times the check happens is always 1 greater than the number of times it passes, (the last check always fails that's when the loop exits), therefore the check happens 5 times for code-2. the loop runs 5 times.